# How to get string representation of a variable as shown by console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

How do I get the string representation of a variable as shown when it's output by `console.log()`?

e.g.,

```
const myFunc = async () => 'my string';
ret = myFunc();
console.log(ret);  // Promise { 'my string' }
stringRepresentation = ret.someMethod(); // is there a method or some other way?
console.assert(stringRepresentation === "Promise { 'my string' }");
```

I'm primarily interested running this in Node.js (but also curious if it's possible when running in a browser).

Comment: Strictly speaking the console doesn't output *string representations.* For many objects it outputs interactive object inspectors. `Promise { 'my string' }` is likely one of those special inspectors. So the answer to your question is mostly *no*.

Comment: ret = myFunc().then(val => console.log(val))

Comment: Thanks @deceze.  I'm mostly interested in running this in Node.js -- does that make it any more possible to get a string representation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node.js console implementation uses `util.inspect` to stringify object output:

```
console.assert(util.inspect(ret) === "Promise { 'my string' }");
```

It's not safe to assert a promise to be `Promise { 'my string' }` because a promise is unnecessarily represented like that. In REPL it will be:

```
Promise {
  'my string',
  domain:
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
```

Even though `util` polyfill exists for browsers, it cannot be used to stringify promises synchronously because native promises cannot be inspected, only chained with `then` or `catch`. Node.js [uses native bindings](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/util/inspect.js#L1094-L1112) to inspect ES6 promises.

Comment: Upvoted for pointing out that Promises don't support synchronous introspection

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a hack to your problem which will work for both browser and Node,

```
function assertPromise(promiseVal, stringVal) {
                promiseVal()
                        .then(str => {
                                let stringRepresentation = `Promise { '${str}' }`;
                                console.assert(stringRepresentation === stringVal);

                        });
}

const myFunc = async () => 'my string';

ret = myFunc();
console.log(ret);  // Promise { 'my string' }

assertPromise(myFunc, "Promise { 'my string' }");       // Assert to TRUE
```